# Indicator format with RectangularRangeIndicator using dojo toolkit

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dojo

I'm trying to use VerticalLinearGauge with RectangularRangeIndicator but I obtain a triangular format(red and green color ) as the image below. I would like the result is a large line, I used the two attributes endThickness and startThickness but no result.

[image]

Help please.

Comment: This is a bug, the problem is fixed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15748680/rectangularrangeindicator-format-like-triangular-using-dojo).

Comment: then you should answer your own question and accept it... :-)